# i couldnt understand this syntax, can someone explain please?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const array = [
    {
        username: "john",
        team: "red",
        score: 5,
        items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "becky",
        team: "blue",
        score: 10,
        items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "susy",
        team: "red",
        score: 55,
        items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
    },
    {
        username: "tyson",
        team: "green",
        score: 1,
        items: ["book", "pen"]
    },

];
```

using this array ,reate an array using forEach that has all the usernames with a "!" to each of the usernames:

```
let newArray = []
array.forEach(user => {
    let { username } = user;
    username = username + "!";
    newArray.push(username);
})

console.log(newArray);
```

i couldnt understand this syntax. i mean why did we use {} after let ?

Comment: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: basically `let { username } = user` is the same as `let username = user.username`

Answer (score 1):

The [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using { } after let is known as object deconstruction. It is a better way of writing `let username = user.username;`. You can learn more about it from [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-object-destructuring-in-javascript)